# Java String immutable, как понять?

Tags: java, строки

Везде в гугле написано, что **при создании immutable объекта его свойства неизменяемы**.
Как мне известно, String является immutable объектом. Тогда объясните мне пожалуйста следующий пример:

```
String test = "test "; //создали объект String
char[] mas = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'}; 
for (char temp : mas) {
   test += temp; //изменяем объект test ?!
}
System.out.println(test);
```

Или я что-то не так понимаю...

Comment: На каждой итерации цикла создаётся новая строка.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но объект остается тот же? То есть где то внутри класса String есть объект, который создается по новому при каждой итерации и добавляет к себе символ? Я так понимаю)

Comment: Нет, каждый раз переменной test присваивается новый объект.

Comment: @h0RNET_ каждый раз создается новый объект типа String и помещается в вашу переменную `test`. Ну иногда может быть возвращен из буфера ранее созданный, если выше по коду уже был использован "test h" или "test he" к примеру. Поэтому строки всегда сравнивают через `equals` и никогда через `==`, поскольку нет гарантии, что это один объект.